# Bind to List(of Custom)

Tags: vb.net, list, charts, controls

I have a vb.net program I am working on where I have created a List of a custom class

```
 Public Shared ImageList As List(Of ZImages)

Public Class ZImages
    Public ID As Integer
    Public FileName As String
    Public GreyIntenStDev As Double
    Public GreyIntenMean As Double
    Public GreyIntenMin As Double
    Public GreyIntenMax As Double
End Class
```

In my code I loop through images, extracting grey scale intensity information which goes into the respective fields below. What I now want to do in real-time is to populate a chart based on the information within the list.

I have seen some stuff which talks about binding array's to a chart control, but I am wondering if someone can help me in binding the X axis to the ID of ImageList, and the Y axis to the GreyIntenStDev.

I thought I may have been able use something like the below, but this does not appear to work;

```
Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(ImageList.ID, ImageList.GreyIntenStDev)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, as most examples I have seen talk about Arrays, not structured lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to create the `IEnumerables` that you want to bind to. The `Select` method can project the list of `ZImages` into the form you want.

```
Dim ids As IEnumerable = ImageList.Select(Function(x) x.ID)
Dim greyIntents as IEnumerable = ImageList.Select(Function(x) x.GreyIntenStDev)

Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(ids, greyIntents)
```

Comment: How does this work in terms of if the list updates, I assume then the method needs to be called again?

Comment: It would, yeah. Another option would be to use the overloaded `DataBindXY` that allows you to specify column names. `Chart1.Series(0).Points.DataBindXY(ImageList, "ID", ImageList, "GreyIntenStDev")` But I believe you would be in the same boat with regards to list updates. I don't think it utilizes any sort of property change notification, does it?